Roots Sage 10 Theme with plugin view not rendering header and footer
I'm working on a Roots Sage 10 project with a plugin for real estate. This plugin has a few files which you place inside your theme folder to render the archive.php and single.php. But this does not render the header and footer from my sage 10 project.
I was told to use \Roots\view('path', [])->render() inside the plugin’s normal template files. But I'm not really familiar with this. Can you guys point me in the right direction to use this? And where to place this to get this working?

What did you tried, and where are you struggling ? Using \Roots\view('path', [])->render() is imo the good way to do such thing, and the documentation could help : https://roots.io/acorn/docs/rendering-blade-views/
